# RoboGuice2.0 ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, roboguice

when I use RoboGuice2.0 to inject some modules, I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException like this

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:129)
at com.google.inject.internal.ap.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.inject.internal.da.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.inject.internal.da.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.inject.internal.da.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.inject.internal.da.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.inject.internal.da.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.inject.internal.bn.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(Unknown Source)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Unknown Source)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Unknown Source)
at roboguice.RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(Unknown Source)
at com.sankuai.movie.MovieApplication.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:984)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3825)
```

I used the setBaseApplicationInjector like this.

```
List<Module> modules = new ArrayList<Module>();
    modules.add(new DefaultNetModule(Consts.BASE_URL));
    modules.add(new DefaultLocationModule(this, false, null, 30000, 5000,
            10000));
    modules.add(new UpdateDownloadModule(this, "movie",
            BaseConfig.sChannel, BaseConfig.sVersionCode,
            BaseConfig.sVersionName, null));
    modules.add(new MovieModule());
    modules.add(new AccountModules(getApplicationContext()));
RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(this, Stage.DEVELOPMENT, Modules
            .override(RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(this)).with(modules));
```

It is likely that it happened in the RoboGuice2.0 source code when I add something to a List.But it seems to be impossible to throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when using list.add method.
I wonder whether my usage is right and the solution to this problem.